# where to get shares trading info

Tags: finance, exchange, trade

I have no idea about finances, trading and other things.

But very interested in passive long term income.

I've read many things about how cheap was microsoft, google, facebook shares in the past.

And will like to find more information about this business of shares exchange.

Thank you.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because questions of this type fit better at money.stackexchange.com but this is too broad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is very broad and perhaps a better fit for https://money.stackexchange.com/.
Historical prices for many securities including the ones you mentioned can be browsed at [Google Finance](https://www.google.com/finance?q=GOOG%2C+FB%2C+MSFT&ei=VtQVVpjTNYiPmAGb4KCQDg).
If you actually want to get into trading, you will need to do so through a brokerage firm, many of which are online with highly featured Web sites.  Exercise a lot of caution before investing and seriously consider diversification (that is, buying an index fund or similar security that aggregates many) instead of investing in just a few individual stocks, to help reduce your risks.

Comment: I agree with WBT: learn about "portfolio diversification" and "index funds" before anything else. That is the contribution that Quantitative Finance has made to investing.